# How to get video capture devices information?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, v4l2

I need to query device information of connected video capture devices (mainly webcams) from C++ code. These information should contain at lease frame-rate, output format and control values (color adjustment).

Comment: Take a look at OpenCV library. Not the tiniest library in the world, but pretty well designed and supports quite a few target platforms (including Windows, Linux, iOS). It has (though limited) video capture support which sounds like it should be enough for your case

Comment: @YePhIcK I'm using OpenCV currently. I suppose it has no API to enumerate video devices and retrieve capabilities, device information, etc.

Comment: AFAIK it does not, it provides a quite limited set of "list, start, get-frame". But you can take a look at the (provided with the library) source code. It has helped me a lot initially, when I had a similar need (on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opencv's [VideoCapture::get(int propId)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) can get you the following info

```
CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC      Current position of the video file in milliseconds or video capture timestamp.
CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES    0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO Relative position of the video file: 0 - start of the film, 1 - end of the film.
CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH   Width of the frames in the video stream.
CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT  Height of the frames in the video stream.
CV_CAP_PROP_FPS           Frame rate.
CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC        4-character code of codec.
CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT   Number of frames in the video file.
CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT        Format of the Mat objects returned by retrieve() .
CV_CAP_PROP_MODE          Backend-specific value indicating the current capture mode.
CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS    Brightness of the image (only for cameras).
CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST      Contrast of the image (only for cameras).
CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION    Saturation of the image (only for cameras).
CV_CAP_PROP_HUE           Hue of the image (only for cameras).
CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN          Gain of the image (only for cameras).
CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE      Exposure (only for cameras).
CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB   Boolean flags indicating whether images should be converted to RGB.
CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE Currently not supported
CV_CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION Rectification flag for stereo cameras (note: only supported by DC1394 v 2.x backend currently)
```

For example:

```
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check it exists
    return -1;
double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

Comment: Nice :) and what about devices? How can I know how many devices are connected? (iterate over `poropId`?)

Comment: "Try" to access devices by index, one by one, until it fails

Comment: You should iterate over the device id passed to the VideoCapture constructor.